# DevExpress: How to get value by index in gridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, devexpress

I have a GridWiew with column `Status Id` and table `Status` in database with colunms `Status Id` and `Value`.

In GridView I need to replace status number to it's value from the table.

[image]

How can I do it with GridView Designer? I think, there should be some property like binding source:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a solution, you can use the [BaseView.GetRow](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.BaseView.GetRow.method) method. This method will return an object that represents your data source item. To get the item's data source index, use the [ColumnView.GetDataSourceRowIndex](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.GetDataSourceRowIndex.method) method.

```
//It is just an example.. 
int dataSourceRowIndex = view.GetDataSourceRowIndex(gridView.FoucsedRowHandle);
//Let suppose you bind with datatable
dataTable.Rows[dataSourceRowIndex]["Status"]=editedValue;
```

You can use the [FocusedRowHandle](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.FocusedRowHandle) property to find the edited row. Also, you can use the [CellValueChanged](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.CellValueChanged) event and its `e.RowHandle` parameter.

To update values in your database, use one of the approaches described in the [Post Data to an Underlying Data Source](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/1082/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/data-binding/post-data-to-an-underlying-data-source) article, depending on the type of your data source.

**References:**
[How to get an item's data source row index of the sorted grid view](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/T546578/how-to-get-an-item-s-data-source-row-index-of-the-sorted-grid-view)
[Update only some details row if master row is selected](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/T808336/update-only-some-details-row-if-master-row-is-selected)